# Custom function will not update automatically (settings are set to auto calculations!)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom function that detects if a cell is bold

```
Function isBold(cellBold)
If cellBold.Font.Bold = True Then
    isBold = 1
ElseIf cellBold.Font.Bold = False Then
    isBold = 0
Else
    isBold = 0
End If

End Function
```

Puts 1 in a cell if the reference cell is bold and 0 if it is not bold
This works well and all the first time around but if I make the reference cell bold the number stays at 0. Automatic calculations are on, the only way for the function to calculate again is to retype the function

Comment: changing cells formatting will never trigger function recalculation, sorry!

Comment: AS @KazJaw states, formatting cells does not trigger a Calculation or a Re-Calculation, And even when a re-calculation is triggered a Non-Volatile function will not re-calculate if the referenced cell value has not been changed. So, while your best best is as Ripster answered, make your function Volatile and while this still won't fire just from a reformat it will fire every time the worksheet is calculated OR Re-Calculated (again will not happen just from changing a cells format). You could also localize Ripster's answer to only the column being referenced, to help with performance issues.

Comment: Out of curiosity (and the fact I think there might be a more sufficient way to solve your problem), WHY would you use this function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding Application.Volatile to the top of your function will make it auto update when the workbook change event is fired.

```
Function isBold(cellBold)
    Application.Volatile
    If cellBold.Font.Bold = True Then
        isBold = 1
    ElseIf cellBold.Font.Bold = False Then
        isBold = 0
    Else
        isBold = 0
    End If
End Function
```

This will not help you if you just bold a result but you can add an event to the sheet you're working on

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Calculate
End Sub
```

If both of these things are in place, your formula will update every time you select a different cell which may work well enough for you. However, I suggest using this method with caution because if you have a very large number of formulas this could slow things down.

-Edit- This should fix the copy paste issue.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim col As Range

    For Each col In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns
        col.Calculate
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works well but it seems like it disabled copy and paste? Oh well not a big deal, i guess I will train them just to use F9 ;)

Answer (score 0):

OK, So I'll be the first to admit this is not an ideal solution, and is pretty hackish. But i think it will fix your solution.

After adding the volatile line to your code as so:

```
Function isBold(cellBold)

Application.Volatile True

If cellBold.Font.Bold = True Then
    isBold = 1
ElseIf cellBold.Font.Bold = False Then
    isBold = 0
Else
    isBold = 0
End If

End Function
```

First Change your Workbook_Open to this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("Sheet1").rngLastCell = Range("A1").Address
    Sheets("Sheet1").fntLastCell = Range("A1").Font.Bold
End Sub
```

Then on the worksheet you are working with (In my example `Sheet1`) Add this to the Worksheet function:

```
Option Explicit
Public fntLastCell As Boolean
Public rngLastCell As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)



If Sheets("Sheet1").Range(rngLastCell).Font.Bold <> fntLastCell Then
    Calculate
End If

    Sheets("Sheet1").rngLastCell = Target.Address
    Sheets("Sheet1").fntLastCell = Target.Font.Bold

End Sub
```

Now to have it work you must Save then close, Then re open your worksheet.

This works by setting 2 global variables each time you select a new cell.

a Boolean variable that states weather the Last Cell selected WAS PREVIOUSLY Bold or not. And a String Variable that references that same Cell. So, you can now check the Bold state of the cell you exited (when it was entered) against the Current Bold State of the cell you just existed and if there was a change it will calculate the workbook. Otherwise nothing will happen.

Hope this works and helps,

Cheers